# Apex Test for Updating Data Category

Tags: apex, unit-test, knowledge

I am very new to Apex code so am looking for some advice.

I have a bit of Apex code which updates the data category based on the field on a knowledge article.

```
public class UpdateDataCategory {   
@InvocableMethod
public static void updateArticleDataCategory(List<Id> knowledgeid){
    List<Knowledge__DataCategorySelection> kADCSLst = new List<Knowledge__DataCategorySelection>();
    List<Knowledge__kav> kArticle = [SELECT ID, Data_Category_1__c FROM Knowledge__kav  WHERE Id IN: knowledgeid];
   for(Knowledge__kav kak: kArticle)
    {
        Knowledge__DataCategorySelection kADCS = new Knowledge__DataCategorySelection();
        kADCS.ParentId = kak.Id;
        kADCS.DataCategoryGroupName = 'Internal';
        kADCS.DataCategoryName = kak.Data_Category_1__c;
        kADCSLst.add(kADCS);
     }
      if(kADCSLst.size()>0)
        {

            insert(kADCSLst);
            system.debug('res**'+kADCSLst);
        }
}
}
```

The code works successfully in sandbox but I am having problems writing a suitable test class.

As far I understand I need to compare the dataCategoryName field on the newly created Knowledge__DataCategorySelection with the Data_Category_1 field on the Knowledge__kav record.

```
    @IsTest
private class KnowledgeTest
{
    @IsTest
    private static void testTrigger()
        {
        Knowledge__kav kk = new Knowledge__kav(Title='title1',urlName='test-article',recordTypeId='0124I0000006TOPQA2',data_category_1__c='Payments');
        insert kk;
            
        List<id> idList = new List<id>();
        idList.add(kk.id);
            
        UpdateDataCategory.updateArticleDataCategory(idList);
        
        List<Knowledge__DataCategorySelection> dataCategory = [SELECT ParentId, DataCategoryGroupName, DataCategoryName   FROM Knowledge__DataCategorySelection
                                                            WHERE ParentId IN: idList];
       
        system.assertEquals(kk.Data_Category_1__c, dataCategory[0].DataCategoryName)      
}
}
```

However I am struggling to access the newly created DataCategorySelection to adequately compare the two fields. I don't think the above Apex Test code fulfils this requirement.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Would very much appreciate any help at all. Thank you!